# Finding duplicate in 2D Vector string

Tags: c++, stl, duplicates

I want to find that whether the 2d Vector table having duplicate or not. I can see lot of programs for removing duplicates by using unique STL algorithm. Which is the best way to find " is Duplicate or not " for 100,000 Records.

Comment: Searching is probably warranted. And that is going to take some code. So what have you got so far?

Comment: Do you want to allow duplicate elements in the `std:vector` and then remove them later? If you don't want duplicate elements at all, consider using `std:set`

Answer (score 0):

I would sort this table, and then search for dups with binary search. This will be `O(n^2 log n)` complexity.   Compare for sorting with something like this:

```
p1.x < p2.x   ||  (p1.x==p2.x  &&  p1.y < p2.y)
```

Most will tell you to use hash table for this, but hash table has `O(n^2)` construction time in worst case. So total complexity will be `O(n^3)`.